# How to decrease a value constantly when countdown is started?

Tags: swift, countdown, discount

I want to merge something with this code. My goal is to add a price value in a label which is decreasing constantly ever second when countdown is started. For ex: CurrentPrice - DiscountPerSecond on first second then CurrentPrice - DiscountPerSecond*2 on second etc.. until countdown is finished.

```
var timerCounter:NSTimeInterval!

   func updateTime(interval: NSTimeInterval) -> String {

        let interval = Int(interval)

        let seconds = interval % 60

        let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60

        let hours =  interval / 3600


        return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)

    }




    func startTimer(hour:Int) {
        timerCounter = NSTimeInterval(hour * 60 * 60)
        let aSelector : Selector = "onTimer:"
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }


    func onTimer(timer:NSTimer!) {
        countdownShow.text = updateTime(timerCounter)
        timerCounter!--

        if (timerCounter == 0) {
            timer.invalidate()
            countdownShow.text = "Event Closed!"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this helpful? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87353/36366

Comment: Nope :( I need to merge it with discounted Price as I mentioned above

Comment: You could use a one second nstimer that triggers X amount of times. Each time it triggers decrease your value. This might not be the best option though since the timer might not be exact in time if triggered like this.

Comment: could you please give me a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

1. Instead of counting down from a time interval, you should store a fixed end date and calculate time intervals from the current time as needed.
2. You should calculate discounts based on a proportion of a maximum discount divided by the proportion of time remaining. (i.e. `price = listPrice - (maximumDiscount * proportionOfTimeElapsed)`)
3. You should use [`NSDateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateComponentsFormatter) to format the remaining time.

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is, but I should warn you that there are serious implications in attempting to bid on items in real time. Unless the user is acting on a purchasing decision independent of anyone else, you are going to have to do significant work to handle n > 1 people tapping the "Buy" button within the same window of time.

Comment: here, user defines the countdown timer as hour on first page, then it uses segue.identifier and passes the info to second page. then countdown begins. I dont know how to do that with NSDate etc. The code above executes countdown timer without an error, however I didn't figure out how to merge discounted Price. All I need when timer continues, Discounted price should decrease constantly in time by a constant discountPerSecond